# I Don't Understand This Recursive Program

Tags: java, recursion

I have this code that uses recursion to get every possible combination of characters for any String entered. But I don't understand whats happening when the program runs! Can someone please explain what occurs in this program? I am still quite new to programming, so I would appreciate it if your explanation isn't too complicated, thanks!

```
public class WordJumble {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String letters = "WORD";
    jumbleWords(letters, "");
  }

  //input parameters
  //word - the remaining letters in the word still to jumble
  //jumbLet - the letters already used to create the jumbled word

  public static void jumbleWords(String word, String jumbLet) {
    int pos;
    String remainingLetters;
    String origWord = word;
    String origJumbledLetters = jumbLet;
    if (word.length() == 1) 
      System.out.println(jumbLet + word);
    else {
      for (pos = 0; pos < origWord.length(); pos++) {
        remainingLetters = origWord.substring(0, pos) + origWord.substring(pos + 1, origWord.length());
        //recursive call to jumbleWords()
        jumbleWords(remainingLetters, origJumbledLetters + origWord.charAt(pos));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The output is then:

```
WORD
WODR
WROD
WRDO
WDOR
WDRO
OWRD
OWDR
ORWD
ORDW
ODWR
ODRW
RWOD
RWDO
ROWD
RODW
RDWO
RDOW
DWOR
DWRO
DOWR
DORW
DRWO
DROW
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use pen and paper and do a dry run with an example. It is the easiest way of understanding this program.

Comment: The best way to understand what is happening is to step through the code, one line at a time, in an IDE debugger.  Try that first and then ask a specific question when you encounter something you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

What this recursive algorithm is doing: is taking in the initial string "WORD"

Then moves one character at a time, once that character has been moved it keeps track of which substrings have been created, and which characters haven't been moved. it passes it back into it self to re jumble the word.

The pos+1 is moving the character item to the next position of the string

Answer (score 0):

If you print out the recursion calls and add an additional parameter that memorizes the recursion depth (and translate to tab-characters), you can perfectly observe what happens:

```
public class WordJumble {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String letters = "WORD";
    jumbleWords(letters, "", 0);
  }

  //input parameters
  //word - the remaining letters in the word still to jumble
  //jumbLet - the letters already used to create the jumbled word

  public static void jumbleWords(String word, String jumbLet, int recursionDepth) {
    int pos;
    String remainingLetters;
    String origWord = word;
    String origJumbledLetters = jumbLet;

    String tabs = "";
    if(recursionDepth > 0) { // translate recursionDepth to tab-characters
        tabs = String.format("%0" + recursionDepth + "d", 0).replace("0","\t");
    }

    if (word.length() == 1) 
      System.out.println(tabs + jumbLet + " + " + word);
    else {
      for (pos = 0; pos < origWord.length(); pos++) {
        remainingLetters = origWord.substring(0, pos) + origWord.substring(pos + 1, origWord.length());
        //recursive call to jumbleWords()
        System.out.println(tabs + "jumbleWords("+remainingLetters+", "+origJumbledLetters + " + " + origWord.charAt(pos) + ");");
        jumbleWords(remainingLetters, origJumbledLetters + origWord.charAt(pos), recursionDepth + 1);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The output is:

```
jumbleWords(ORD,  + W);
    jumbleWords(RD, W + O);
        jumbleWords(D, WO + R);
            WOR + D
        jumbleWords(R, WO + D);
            WOD + R
    jumbleWords(OD, W + R);
        jumbleWords(D, WR + O);
            WRO + D
        jumbleWords(O, WR + D);
            WRD + O
    jumbleWords(OR, W + D);
        jumbleWords(R, WD + O);
            WDO + R
        jumbleWords(O, WD + R);
            WDR + O
jumbleWords(WRD,  + O);
    jumbleWords(RD, O + W);
        jumbleWords(D, OW + R);
            OWR + D
        jumbleWords(R, OW + D);
            OWD + R
    jumbleWords(WD, O + R);
        jumbleWords(D, OR + W);
            ORW + D
        jumbleWords(W, OR + D);
            ORD + W
    jumbleWords(WR, O + D);
        jumbleWords(R, OD + W);
            ODW + R
        jumbleWords(W, OD + R);
            ODR + W
jumbleWords(WOD,  + R);
    jumbleWords(OD, R + W);
        jumbleWords(D, RW + O);
            RWO + D
        jumbleWords(O, RW + D);
            RWD + O
    jumbleWords(WD, R + O);
        jumbleWords(D, RO + W);
            ROW + D
        jumbleWords(W, RO + D);
            ROD + W
    jumbleWords(WO, R + D);
        jumbleWords(O, RD + W);
            RDW + O
        jumbleWords(W, RD + O);
            RDO + W
jumbleWords(WOR,  + D);
    jumbleWords(OR, D + W);
        jumbleWords(R, DW + O);
            DWO + R
        jumbleWords(O, DW + R);
            DWR + O
    jumbleWords(WR, D + O);
        jumbleWords(R, DO + W);
            DOW + R
        jumbleWords(W, DO + R);
            DOR + W
    jumbleWords(WO, D + R);
        jumbleWords(O, DR + W);
            DRW + O
        jumbleWords(W, DR + O);
            DRO + W
```